# how to render table from json input react

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering an Json from DB and want to dispay the json in interactive table.

Using react 17.0.1 version

```
[
    {
        "Sno": "1",
        "First Name": "name",
        "Last Name": "las2t name",
        "Email": "test@gmail.com",
        "Amount": "2000"
    },
   {
        "Sno": "1",
        "First Name": "first name",
        "Last Name": "last name",
        "Email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "Amount": "2000"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the data as an array and map it inside the custom HTML table or use any react-table. Here is how you do it.

let say your data is fetched in data[] array from the database,
then you can map it like this

```
{data.map((l, i) => (
       <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Sno</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th>
     <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{l.sno}</td>
    <td>{l.FirstName}</td>
    <td>{l.LastName}</td>
    <td>{l.Email}</td>
    <td>{l.Amount}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing of data and rendering it in the client side is left to the developers to handle. React doesn't do it for us. You can use `react-table` with little bit of configuration you can customize as you want.